# Why won't ubuntuone service start automatically at boot?

Tags: boot, ubuntu-one, startup

If I'm not mistaken, the ubuntuone sync service is supposed to start automatically during the boot/login process. But I'm finding that it doesn't on either of my 10.10 computers (one an AMD64 desktop and the other an i386 laptop). I'm using the ubuntuone-indicator, but the problem began before I installed it. In my list of startup applications I find one titled "Ubuntu One" with this command line

```
/bin/sh -c '[ -d "$HOME/Ubuntu One" ] && ubuntuone-launch'
```

But the only way for me to start the service is to open the Ubuntu One setup UI and click "connect" every time I start up the computer. Any suggestions as to what might be going wrong?

Here is the message output when I run `u1sdtool --status` after startup (i.e., before starting the Ubuntu One service manually):

> Oops, an error ocurred: Traceback (most recent call last): Failure: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/lib/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone-syncdaemon exited with status 1

Could the problem be related to the fact that I'm using connman and the experimental indicator-network package to connect to the internet?

Comment: Could you post the output of `u1sdtool --status` before you start it up manually?

Comment: The output of that command is the following:  Oops, an error ocurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/lib/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone-syncdaemon exited with status 1

Comment: What version of python-ubuntuone-client do you have installed?

Comment: It's version 1.4.4.1

Answer (score 1):

It does not start automatically on boot because it needs to know for witch user to connect, in case there are more users set for computer login.

There is a Startup section in the System drop down menu, where you can add it to start automatically at login.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this answer. As I said in my question, there is a command in my "startup programs" section to start ubuntu one at login. But it's clearly not working and I don't know why. The fact that this is happening on both my computers is especially odd, since both computers have the star script included in the startup commands.

Comment: It needs the keyring, witch asks for a password later, after startup. No keyring acces, no Ubuntuone.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably file a bug: https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client. You should also attach your `.cache/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.log` to the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

There is a start up bug that has affected quite a few people [bug #683116](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/683116). The fix is in the pipeline and we should see it soon.